# convert c enum bitfield to python

Tags: python, enums

Looking at kismet's source code in packet_ieee80211.h is the section

```
enum crypt_type {
    crypt_none = 0,
crypt_unknown = 1,
crypt_wep = (1 << 1),
crypt_layer3 = (1 << 2),
// Derived from WPA headers
crypt_wep40 = (1 << 3),
crypt_wep104 = (1 << 4),
crypt_tkip = (1 << 5),
crypt_wpa = (1 << 6),
crypt_psk = (1 << 7),
crypt_aes_ocb = (1 << 8),
crypt_aes_ccm = (1 << 9),
//WPA Migration Mode
crypt_wpa_migmode = (1 << 19),
// Derived from data traffic
crypt_leap = (1 << 10),
crypt_ttls = (1 << 11),
crypt_tls = (1 << 12),
crypt_peap = (1 << 13),
crypt_isakmp = (1 << 14),
    crypt_pptp = (1 << 15),
crypt_fortress = (1 << 16),
crypt_keyguard = (1 << 17),
crypt_unknown_nonwep = (1 << 18),
};
```

I understand this as shifting bits but that's about it. Suppose I have the int 706, how do I break this number up into the cryptset as defined above i.e. how can I extract which crypts are used give 706 especially ported to python

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aruisdante's answer is very good, I just wanted to expand on the answer if you have to use a Python previous to 3.4, as there [does exist a backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) on PyPI:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Crypt(IntEnum):
    none = 0
    unknown = 1
    wep = (1 << 1)
    layer3 = (1 << 2)
    # Derived from WPA headers
    wep40 = (1 << 3)
    wep104 = (1 << 4)
    tkip = (1 << 5)
    wpa = (1 << 6)
    psk = (1 << 7)
    aes_ocb = (1 << 8)
    aes_ccm = (1 << 9)
    # WPA Migration Mode
    wpa_migmode = (1 << 19)
    # Derived from data traffic
    leap = (1 << 10)
    ttls = (1 << 11)
    tls = (1 << 12)
    peap = (1 << 13)
    isakmp = (1 << 14)
    pptp = (1 << 15)
    fortress = (1 << 16)
    keyguard = (1 << 17)
    unknown_nonwep = (1 << 18)

    @classmethod
    def find_crypts(cls, magic_number):
        crypts = []
        for mask in cls:
            if magic_number & mask == mask:
                crypts.append(mask)
        if len(crypts) > 1:
            # remove false positive of none
            crypts = crypts[1:]
        return crypts

print Crypt.find_crypts(0)
[<Crypt.none: 0>]
print Crypt.find_crypts(706)
[<Crypt.wep: 2>, <Crypt.wpa: 64>, <Crypt.psk: 128>, <Crypt.aes_ccm: 512>]
```

Answer (score 8):

So, what you have to understand here is that this enum is defining a series of [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). In this case, each one of these enum values, in binary, contains one and only one `1`. For example,

```
crypt_wep = (1 << 1) = 0b10
crypt_wpa = (1 << 6) = 0b1000000
```

And so on. Using the bitshift operator is just an easy way of representing *'I want the nth+1 binary digit to be the flag'*

This lets us bitwise `or` a bunch of these values together and get a *magic number* that describes a combination of these crypt values uniquely as bit flags. To test if a *magic number* contains a value, we can simply bitwise `and` it with the value we wish to test

```
magic_number = crypt_wep | crypt_wpa
has_wep      = (magic_number & crypt_wep) == crypt_wep
has_wpa      = (magic_number & crypt_wpa) == crypt_wpa
```

`has_wep` and `has_wpa` will be `true` if and only if `magic_number` contained those bit flags.

So lets look at the number `706`, which in binary is `0b1011000010`. We can look at this and immediately see that it must have been built with `crypt_wep`, `crypt_wpa`, `crypt_psk` and `crypt_aes_ccm`, because the correct bits are set for those values.

So how to port to python? Well, python has [enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) just like C/C++ does if you're in python 3.4 or later. So you can simply create the same enum table in python, and apply the same bitwise tests to determine what your *magic number* represents. If you're on a version of python that doesn't have enums, you can simply define a class with some static constants in it to get the same effect (and build in a method to test for the set of crypts a magic number contains). Such a class could look like this:

```
class CryptKeys(object):
    crypt_masks = {
                    'crypt_unknown':1,
                     ....
                    'crypt_unknown_nonwep': (1 << 18)
                   }
    @classmethod
    def find_crypts(cls, magic_number):
        if magic_number == 0:
            return ['crypt_none']
        else:
            return [name for name, mask in cls.crypt_masks.items() if magic_number & mask == mask]
```