# Best way to handle lots of constants with more than one semantics

Tags: python

I intend to implement a library which includes lots of constants. Now there are already many questions about constants on stackoverflow. But I am pondering about a special case which complicates things and I am not sure which way to go. Probably someone already solved a similar problem and can help me avoid obvious fails :).

To be more precise, I am going to implement SMPP (short message p2p) related stuff. SMPP consists of many fields which have different possible values which sometimes are composed of different parts. The esm_class field for example is an 8 bit integer, bits 1-0, 5-2 and 7-6 being 'sub fields'. So the value esm_class consists of three constants 'concatenated' together.

But the story goes on. The esm_class subfields have different meanings depending on the type of message they are being used in.

Now a few questions arose:

1. What's the best way, to organise the different constants?
2. How do I define different constants for the same field (or subfield)?
3. What's the best way to add a description to each constant?

For question 3 I went for tupels: CONST_NAME = (0x01, 'value meaning',).

My first idea for the other problems was to organise the constants in modules. This would for example give us:

- constants.esm_class which contains all esm_class values
- constants.data_coding which contains all possible encodings
- etc (for each field a module in constants)

For data_coding this works well. But esm_class actually consists of 'subfields'. So I thought about:

- constants.esm_class.types for the message type subfield
- constants.esm_class.modes for the message modes
- constants.esm_class.features for the features field

This already is quite long, resulting in constants.esm_class.features.UDHI_AND_REPLAY_PATH for example. Not very nice, somehow. And that's not yet all I need... actually I even need to split the constants.esm_class.types apart because the type values have different meanings in different contexts (basically incoming messages vs. outgoing short messages). So this would result in even one more submodule, if I followed the schema: constants.esm_class.types.outgoing and constants.esm_class.types.incoming

Additionally, I also need a way to concatenate types, modes and features to create the esm_class value and I also need to split esm_class apart for parsing. So there needs to be a generic way to build field values from constants and also to detect that a certain value is illegal (i.e. has a value not defined by a constant).

My question: What do you think is the best way I should follow? Should I go for classes? As I've read best practice with python is to define constants on module level. I also see some issues with using classes. So probably a new data type for each possible field would do it? I'm stuck and looking forward to your ideas!

**Edit:** I intend to use the lib with python 3.3+ and probably I want to make it compatible to 2.7, so Enums from Python 3.4 unfortunately are no solution.

**Edit 2:** Probably I packed too much information in too few text. So I will give an example.

esm_class in SMPP is kind of a derived value, consisting of a type, a mode and a feature. If the esm_class for example has the value 00111100, in fact it means that the feature equals to 00, the mode to 1111 and the type again 00. That's what i refer to as a "subtype". The constants will be put together with bitwise operations.

Comment: I could not follow your entire question, but how about dictionaries?

Comment: Using tuples as the answer to question 3 seems to conflate code with documentation.

Comment: @chepner Tupels seemed right because I also want to be able to tell the user what the value means (e.g. I want to tell the user that the message is encoded in UCS-2). So it is both, documentation and output. But I am not convinced that this is the best solution :). Do you have suggestions?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324957/convert-c-enum-bitfield-to-python/23325125#23325125 might be a good place for you to start with respect to your bit-fields problems.

Comment: The version of python you're on would also be very helpful to know. ``Enums`` in Python 3.4+ would be quite useful for your problem since they're essentially static class instantiations with attributes/methods. But obviously only helpful if you have access to them.

Comment: @user2963623 Well, dictionaries lead to consts.esm_class['types']['incoming'] instead of consts.esm_class.types.incoming. Probably this improves the situation, because there is not the ugly directory structure, yep. But somehow it is less obvioius that they are constants that way.

Comment: I couldn't follow your entire question either. Could you clarify what you mean by the following terms? "Constant", "value", "field", "type", "mode", "feature".

Comment: The question is, does the *program* need to be able to access the descriptions? If not, there's no point cluttering your code with unnecessary tuples. It forces the user to remember that he has to write `CONST[0]` instead of just `CONST`, which incurs both extra typing and extra running time (for the indexing).

Comment: A final thing to remember is that you can completely mask the length of an import chain by properly setting up imports in various ``__init__.py``'s, so long as there are no name-space collisions.

Comment: @balu Constant as in CONSTANT = 'value' to be used instead of a fixed string. "type", "mode" and "feature" are encoded in the esm_class field. The esm_class for example is 00111100 and consists of feature (00), mode (1111) and type (00). I am going to modify the question.

Comment: Generally speaking:
1. I think it helps to try to clarify for yourself what your protocol hierarchy is – i.e. which protocol structures depend on which other structures. You said that the meaning of some of the structures' properties depend on the context. Might it be possible to separate this context from the structure itself?
2. In the protocols I implement (I'm not familiar with SMPP) I always try to think of objects being sent and received because this makes it easy to translate the protocol hierarchy to a class hierarchy.

Comment: As for enums in Python < 3.4, there's https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34 .

Comment: @chepner you got a point. How would you store the information what the human readable representation of a constant is?

Comment: @balu Thank you, I was googling that right now :). Probably this really solves my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make an attempt at giving an answer (I hope I've understood you correctly). Elaborating on my comments above, I would go for something like:

```
class esm_class:
    BITMASK_FEATURE = 0b11000000
    BITMASK_MODE    = 0b00111100
    BITMASK_TYPE    = 0b00000011

    class Features:
        FEATURE_1 = 0b00
        FEATURE_2 = 0b01
        FEATURE_3 = 0b10
        FEATURE_4 = 0b11

    class Modes:
        MODE_1 = 0b0000
        # …

    class Types:
        TYPE_1 = 0b00
        TYPE_2 = 0b01
        # …

    def __init__(self, type_, mode, feature):
        self.type = type_
        self.mode = mode
        self.feature = feature

    def __bytes__(self):
        '''
        Use this to write an instance of esm_class to a file-like 
        object or stream, e.g..: 
        mysocket.send(bytes(my_esm_class_obj))
        '''
        return ((self.feature << 6) | (self.mode << 2) |
                self.type).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, filelike):
        '''
        Use this to parse incoming data from a file-like object
        and create an instance of esm_class accordingly, e.g:
        my_esm_class_obj = esm_class.parse(stream)
        '''
        instance = cls()
        data = filelike.read(1)
        instance.feature = int.from_bytes((data & cls.BITMASK_FEATURE) >> 6)
        instance.mode = int.from_bytes((data & cls.BITMASK_MODE) >> 2)
        instance.mode = int.from_bytes((data & cls.BITMASK_TYPE) >> 2)
```

Now, the code can certainly be optimized but the point is: I tried to abstract away the binary representation as soon as possible, in order to arrive at a class hierarchy representing the structures appearing in the protocol. Accordingly, I didn't simply put the constants / the values in different modules but organized them in such a way that they appear together with the structure they are part of – which is also the structure you're going to use in the rest of your code.

Further things to note:

- You can certainly omit the classes `Features`, `Modes` and `Types` if you like and put all values in the scope of `esm_class`. However, I would do this only if the symbols' names `FEATURE_1`, `MODE_2` and so on make it clear which part of the bitstring they correspond to (i.e. the feature part or the mode part or…).
- I would usually avoid Python 3.4's enums because IMO they are tedious to deal with when you need to access a symbol's value (i.e. its `value` attribute) but that's also because I don't need the symbols' names themselves. You mileage may vary.
- Finally, in the comments above, chepner made a very good point regarding whether to store descriptions in your code at all. I recommend you follow his advice.

Comment: Thank you very much! You got it right :). I think that your approach is a good one. Just one question remains: If I want to output information on constants... how would you store the description of a constant? As in: "Received message encoded as {}".format(description_of_encoding_constant)

Comment: Is this for logging purposes or is this an integral part of your program?

Comment: Both. For example I want to be able to output "Encoding x is not supported" instead of "You used an encoding which is not supported" (more user friendly).

Comment: In the former case, you could simply define a dictionary at a place where it doesn't clutter your important code (in the logging function for instance). In the latter case, you should indeed consider using Python 3.4's `enum`. I'd probably go for `enum` in both cases because I find maintaining such a dict quite tedious.

Comment: I just read the whole enum documentation. If I got it right, you can output the key as a string, but not freely choose a descriptive text?

Comment: Would it be good practice to define a custom method which declares the dict and returns the text according to the given Enum member?

Comment: As for your first question: Yep. As for your 2nd one: If those descriptions were really important, I'd try to avoid a separate dictionary in order to keep the descriptions right where the symbols are defined. Hence, I would either extend the `Enum` class somehow (such that enum members also have a `description` attribute) or just use a tuple as value.

Comment: I will do either of these. Thanks again!

Comment: *However* don't forget that your `esm_class` is really a low-level class, meaning that users of your class will be familiar with the protocol and all those symbols anyway. Hence, I see no point in providing detailed descriptions because there's an exhausive documentation somewhere, anyway. If anything, define those descriptions on an upper layer in case you need to explain the symbols to the end user. (Yet, I *highly doubt* that there's need for that because the purpose of upper layers is usually to hide all those details from that same user.)

Comment: Good point. Probably I will really just define texts on a higher level where required. In fact, such texts are only required for parts of the constants I define.